# julia-lang Cache data in a parallel thread using @async

Tags: parallel-processing, async-await, julia

Suppose we have a slow function to produce data and another slow function to process data as follow:

```
# some slow function
function prime(i)
  sleep(2)
  println("processed $i")
  i
end

function slow_process(x)
  sleep(2)
  println("slow processed $x")
end

function each(rng)
  function _iter()
    for i ∈ rng
      @time d = prime(i)
      produce(d)
    end
  end
  return Task(_iter)
end

@time for x ∈ each(1000:1002)
  slow_process(x)
end
```

Output:

```
% julia test-task.jl
processed 1000
  2.063938 seconds (37.84 k allocations: 1.605 MB)
slow processed 1000
processed 1001
  2.003115 seconds (17 allocations: 800 bytes)
slow processed 1001
processed 1002
  2.001798 seconds (17 allocations: 800 bytes)
slow processed 1002
 12.166475 seconds (88.08 k allocations: 3.640 MB)
```

Is there some way to get and cache data in a parallel thread using @async and feed to the `slow_process` function?

Edit: I updated the example to clarify the problem. Ideally, the example should take 2+6 seconds instead of 12 seconds.

Edit 2: This is my effort of using @sync and @async but I got the error `ERROR (unhandled task failure): no process with id 2 exists`

```
macro swap(x,y)
  quote
    local tmp = $(esc(x))
    $(esc(x)) = $(esc(y))
    $(esc(y)) = tmp
  end
end

# some slow function
function prime(i)
  sleep(2)
  println("processed $i")
  i
end

function slow_process(x)
  sleep(2)
  println("slow processed $x")
end

function each(rng)
  @assert length(rng) > 1
  rng = collect(rng)
  a = b = nothing
  function _iter()
    for i ∈ 1:length(rng)
      if a == nothing
        a = @async remotecall_fetch(prime, 2, rng[i])
        b = @async remotecall_fetch(prime, 2, rng[i+1])
      else
        if i < length(rng)
          a = @async remotecall_fetch(prime, 2, rng[i+1])
        end
        @swap(a,b)
      end
      @sync d = a
      produce(d)
    end
  end
  return Task(_iter)
end

@time for x ∈ each(1000:1002)
  slow_process(x)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have the working solution below:

```
macro swap(x,y)
  quote
    local tmp = $(esc(x))
    $(esc(x)) = $(esc(y))
    $(esc(y)) = tmp
  end
end

# some slow function
@everywhere function prime(i)
  sleep(2)
  println("prime $i")
  i
end

function slow_process(x)
  sleep(2)
  println("slow_process $x")
end

function each(rng)
  @assert length(rng) > 1
  rng = collect(rng)
  a = b = nothing
  function _iter()
    for i ∈ 1:length(rng)
      if a == nothing
        a = remotecall(prime, 2, rng[i])
        b = remotecall(prime, 2, rng[i+1])
      else
        if i < length(rng)
          a = remotecall(prime, 2, rng[i+1])
        end
        @swap(a,b)
      end
      d = fetch(a)
      produce(d)
    end
  end
  return Task(_iter)
end
@time for x ∈ each(1000:1002)
  slow_process(x)
end
```

And

```
% julia -p 2 test-task.jl
8.354102 seconds (148.00 k allocations: 6.204 MB)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer that was taken is parallelism based on process. I could provide an idea of parallelism based on thread:

```
# some slow function
function prime(i)
    sleep(2)
    println("processed $i")
    i
end

function slow_process(x)
    sleep(2)
    println("slow processed $x")
end

function each(rng)
    function _iter()
        @time d = prime(rng)
        produce(d)
    end
    return Task(_iter)
end

@time @sync for i = 1000:1002
    x = each(i)
    @async slow_process(copy(x))
end
```

I presume `x` should be prodeced serially and `slow_process` should be not. I just moved the loop inside `each` out.

ps: I could not succeed in executing both your original code and my providing code. So I just provide an idea.